# The length of the Shortest Cycle in an Undirected Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, undirected-graph

I am given an algorithm that is supposed to find the length of the shortest cycle in an undirected graph with unit edge lengths. I have to show that the algorithm does not always work by providing a counterexample. I am having problems coming up with an example that can show that this algorithm does not always work.

---

Algorithm:

- Do a depth-first search, keeping track of the level of each vertex.
- Each time a back edge is encountered, compute the cycle length and save it if it is smaller than the shortest one previously seen.

---

Any suggestions/ help will be appreciated

Comment: well, that's all pretty nice so far. But i don't see any code for the actual algorithm...

Comment: What's the algorithm?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom updated the question

Answer (score 3):

Look at this graph with the given traversal:

[image]

When you encounter backedge `e->a` you note a cycle with length `5` and for `e->b` - a cycle with length `4`. However, the answer is `3` produced by the cycle `a-b-e`.